# What are the ways to migrate old data from EBS database tables to another database 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle-ebs

I need to migrate old data from oracle EBS to our database which is oracle 12c.
In our database we have approx. fifteen tables in which i have to migrate data.

The challenges are:

- Table structures are totally different at our end.
- All data is relational.
- It is approximate half one million records (for one table i.e user table)
- Other tables are storing user details like bank related data, sites data, 
  invoice records, audit trail etc and data will be more than the user table 
  data.
- Tables are not empty. They all have live data.

so,

1. What are the possible ways in oracle db to perform this task?
2. What steps should i follow for perfect migration of data?

Please help me out. Thank You!

Comment: Are both databases live? Or is it just the new (target) database which is updating?

Comment: yes both are live. Previously all the work was done through ebs but currently we developed another web application to collect and process data. After that some plsql procedures pull data from our database and push to EBS back and further process is done on EBS end.

Comment: And the intention is to keep both databases live and bounce data between them? Hmm. I think your question will get closed as Too Broad. There are too many clarifications required. Frankly it would be better suited to a short term consultancy gig than a StackOverflow question

Comment: Yes it is too broad but i need your help. I only want to know what will be the steps and which oracle utility should i use sqlldr, import or anything else.

Comment: If you need to migrate data, then your destination should be prepared to accommodate it and that's that. For this to happen, you need DataLoad or a similar utility. Here's the Oracle documentation for the different methods: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/impexp.htm

Comment: *"I only want to know what will be the steps and which oracle utility should i use "* Ah there's the catch. So much depends upon the details of your scenario, it's hard to offer even a vague strategy let alone some concrete tactics. Although it seems unlikely that either `sqlldr` or  `imp` (or `data_pump`) is what you need, as you're not really migrating data are you? Both databases are live, so actually you're shipping data (i.e. replication) , for which Oracle has a variety of options, some rather pricy (*cough* GoldenGate *cough*).

Comment: @APC - it is only one time activity. Task is to migrate EBS data which is not created through our new application, but it was created in EBS previously until our application was not live . Current workflow is : user to create invoice ---> Web Application ---> Database 12c(our db) ------> EBS DB ------>ASN creation Done. Sorry if it is wrongly titled.

Comment: So you didn't mean it when you said two days ago *"both are live ... After that some plsql procedures pull data from our database and push to EBS back and further process is done on EBS end"*???

Comment: Sir, yes both are live and, data travels from our db to EBS DB (Through web application new user can register, create invoices and many other things and then this data is sent to EBS and this process is working perfectly. But these are new records, we don't have the old user records which was ever created in EBS when all the process was done through EBS not through any other medium. We require that data in our db so that it could be processed through newly created web application.

Comment: @APC - Previously i have done data migration using sql loader by creating CSVs. That was the fresh database and records were less, not this much but here the scenario is totally different. As  i am db person, all the responsibility is on my head. I do not see any path.